# How to record an applescript in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, applescript

I open ScriptEditor, click on Record, click on some icons in the doc, open System Preferences, then click stop in the ScriptEditor and nothing happens, meaning I get no script. Nothing was recorded.

Has anyone being able to record any applescript using Script Editor under Snow Leopard? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

-Sergio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only record applications that are written to be recordable. Try recording some actions in the Finder, and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't been able to record much of anything in any of the standard Apple programs...System Preferences for instance. Seems like there should be some more feedback from the system on Apple's part.

Comment: I know.. this is no place for rants, but I can't contain myself.. how useless !!!

Comment: This is because Cocoa, which modern Mac apps are written in, doesn't provide any API for sending events to be recorded, though developers can still use the older Apple Event Manager API from a Cocoa app (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_about_apps/SAppsAboutApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001976-SW21)

Answer (score 2):

There are very few modern recordable AppleScript apps. In addition to Finder, BareBones' excellent free TextWrangler text-editing app is recordable (as is the pro BBEdit editor); Fetch, the FTP client, is recordable.